# Python workspace

Tags: arcpy, arccatalog, workspace, python-window

I wrote a simple script to rename about 15 shapefiles in a folder on our local server.  When I tested it I was working on a workspace on the C:\ and it worked fine. All our data is on a local server and when I changed the pathname to (... arcpy.env.workspace = "P:\Alabama\Export") it did not work.  I eventually have to use 20 or so diff paths so I don't want to have to copy data to my c drive.

As I read through examples they all seem to use something on C:.

I am running it in the Python window in ArcCatalog not on an IDE

Sample:

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "P:\Alabama\Export"

 if arcpy.Exists("Histori2.shp"):
    arcpy.Rename_management("Histori2.shp", "H_BEV_CANS.shp")

 if arcpy.Exists("Histori3.shp"):
     arcpy.Rename_management("Histori3.shp", "H_CANS.shp")
```

Comment: C: is just the standard drive letter, so that is why it is used for examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Python, the backslash character is treated as an escape character. `\n` is the newline character, `\t` is a tab....

There are a few different ways you can get it to work:

1. Change your backslashes to forward slashes (Python accepts either). `"P:/Alabama/Export"`
2. Double your backslashes (escape the escape). `"P:\\Alabama\\Export"`
3. Format as raw string (escape characters are ignored). `r"P:\Alabama\Export"`

Comment: I'm a fan of **3**, since it's easy to do `r''` and copy/paste a raw path from the File Explorer path. Super quick and easy.

Comment: +1 @Mike Toews.  And in case anyone didn't know the "super trick" for copying the full path and filename of a file from Windows Explorer, `SHIFT + (Right-click)` on a file provides a normally "hidden" extra option to `"Copy as Path"`.

Comment: @RyanDalton that's a really strange option to hide in a extra menu.

Comment: WHAAAAT?! Gosh, and here I was right clicking and navigating through the tabs, highlighting the object name. Why in the world isn't this in the normal right click?

Comment: You can get a shell extension called [Copy Path](http://copypath.codeplex.com/) that adds the item directly to the context menu and works on XP as well as 7. Such a huge timesaver.

Comment: Number 2 always works for me. Used to use number 1, but found was too inconsistent. Never had a problem with 3.

Comment: Ok that worked, thank you!  Now I am trying to list and rename shapefiles in all the folders within the Alabama folder. I thought to list then loop with a for statement something like this:                                     >>> import arcpy

... arcpy.env.workspace = "P:\WSMR4 18K\Working_Files\Daily GPS Files\Alabama\05-30-2013\Export"

for fc in arcpy.ListDatasets("*")
... if arcpy.Exists("Histori2.shp"):
...     arcpy.Rename_management("Histori2.shp", "H_BEV_CANS.shp")
... 
... if arcpy.Exists("Histori3.shp"):
...     arcpy.Rename_management("Histori3.shp", "H_CANS.shp")  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rachael please make this a new question.