# FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion in ArcGis 10.1

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I have many > 60 .dwg files I want to convert just the polyline parts of these and have put together a list of python commands using excel to get something like this:

[image]

However when I try running this in the python window or from a saved script I keep getting input features and output location do not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please update the post to include a zoomed-zoomed in command, so that we can see what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Oops, edited with link to larger version

Comment: See the answer [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68236/python-workspace/68238#68238).

Comment: looks to me the wrong thing is feature class to feature class. you should use the from CAD to feature class function.

Answer (score 4):

Your file paths need to be formatted properly.  For example:

Instead of:

```
"C:\path\to\yourfile"
```

Change to:

```
r"C:\path\to\yourfile"
```

or

```
"C:/path/to/yourfile"
```

or

```
"C:\\path\\to\\yourfile"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm now getting this:

http://i.imgur.com/vVz3EkR.png

Comment: I can see the paths are still formatted improperly.  Additionally, the third parameter needs only quotation marks and not string literal formatting.  parameter 1 should be `r"C:\path"`, parameter 2 should be `r"C:\path"` and parameter 3 should be `"1-ALLEN-ALLEN-SITE-001_Polyline"`.

Comment: I've just done that and still can't get it to work:

http://i.imgur.com/LWmAV45.png

Comment: I notice that your file name is different in screenshot2.  It changed from `"1-ALLEN-ALLEN-SITE-001_Polyline"` to `"1--ALLEN-ALLEN-SITE-001_Polyline"`.  I would also recommend  reassessing your naming protocol to include underscores as the only special characters and never use a special character to lead (e.g. _PS).

Answer (score 1):

try putting a lower case r before both locations in each of the commands and try executing it from the python window. This tells python to treat them as a literal string (it's probably hitting \a in your username which is reserved) . Should read similar to below:

```
arcpy.FeatureClasstoFeatureClass_conversion(r"C:\....", r"C:\....", "nameoffile")
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the "-" in the filenames it did not like!